# How to set offset between elements using popper.js?

Tags: javascript, popper.js

This is how I create my popper object:

```
varpositioner = new Popper($(".js-search-container").get(0),
    $(".js-search").get(0),
    {
        placement: 'bottom-start',
            offsets: {
                top: '10px',
            }
    }
);
```

I want to create some offset between the `js-search-container` and the `js-search` objects, but my attempt at setting an offset seems to have no effect.

My investigations thus far:

- I have looked at the popper.js documentation, but haven't figured out the exact syntax I need to use.
- I have searched for examples but haven't found any example using offset that seem to work with popper.js v1/latest.

Answer (score 7):

Use this code instead.

```
varpositioner = new Popper($element, tip, {
      placement: attachment,
      modifiers: {
        offset: {
          offset: "-10,0"
        }
      });
```